# Batch Search for file and copy path to copy a new file to the paths found

Tags: batch-file, log4j

I am trying to make a batch where it searches for all files that contain log4j-core and stores all the path to a text file so I can copy a new updated file with a different version to all the paths that were found. This is what I have so far.

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd \
ECHO SEARCHING FOR log4j-core THIS MAY TAKE SOME TIME...
dir /s /b log4j-core*.jar >%tmp%\path.txt
echo delims
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%tmp%\path.txt) do (set path=%%~dpa && copy /b /y "c:\Temp\Script\patch.jar" "%path%\log4j-core-2.17.2.jar")
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't actually ask a question, there are problems with your code.

`%temp%` by default contains spaces, hence you need to quote `%tmp%\path.txt` wherever it is used, thus: `"%tmp%\path.txt"`

This means that you need `"usebackq delims="` in your `for /f` otherwise the `for` will analyse the *string* `"%tmp%\path.txt"`, not the *file* `"%tmp%\path.txt"` as intended.

Next problem is the `set` statement. Batch is sensitive to spaces in an ordinary string `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N". Use `set "var1=value"` for setting **STRING** values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces.

Don't use `path` as a variablename - it's a reserved word in batch, meaning the sequence in which the directories are searched to find an executable that isn't in the current directory.

Next is the minor matter of `delayedexpansion`. You are invoking `delayedexpansion` but not using it. Please read [Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

Once we've tackled all of that, we come to simplification.

Whatever variable name you use, `%~dp?` returns the pathname including a terminal backslash, so you don't need to insert it again in the destination filename for your `copy`.

You don't need to use the intermediate variable - only if you are manipulating the string. `"%%~dpaog4j-core-2.17.2.jar"` will work quite adequately for your copy-destination, remembering that `%%~dpa` will be resolved to a string with terminal backslash.

The `echo` statement will simply display the string `delims` and seems pointless.

It's probably academic, but the `dir` command should contain `/a-d` to exclude any directory names that match the pattern, unlikely though that may be.

I'd also suggest that `where /r \ log4j-core*.jar` should produce the same results as the `dir` command. Note that there are two parameters to `where /r` - a directory name and a filename-pattern to match. If the filename-pattern does not have an extension, it required a terminal `.` otherwise `.*` is assumed.

And finally, `for /f` can process the list produced by a command, see `for /?` from the prompt or thousands of examples on SO.

So, all in all, your code could be reduced to

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r \ log4j-core*.jar') do copy /b /y "c:\Temp\Script\patch.jar" "%%~dpalog4j-core-2.17.2.jar"
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

It would be wise to simply `echo` the `copy` command for verification

And I'll say again, always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Comment: Thank you this worked exactly how I wanted. I was having issues with the code not working as I expected. Thank you very much!